# Typescript discriminated union not narrowing

Tags: typescript, types, discriminated-union

I have several shapes types and intersect functions that operate on pairs of specific shape types. I am trying to create a function that returns a mapping of these functions. I have create a discriminated union of the shapes, and have defined the intersect function as a single type that operates on the discriminated union Shape type. I get a type error when trying to build the map:

```js
enum ShapeType {
  sphere = 0,
  box = 1,
}

type Sphere = {
  type: ShapeType.sphere;
  radius: number;
};

type Box = {
  type: ShapeType.box;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  depth: number;
};

type Shape = Sphere | Box;

type IntersectFunction = (a: Shape, b: Shape) => boolean;

function intersectSphereSphere(a: Sphere, b: Sphere): boolean {
  return true;
}

function intersectBoxBox(a: Box, b: Box): boolean {
  return true;
}

function intersectBoxSphere(a: Box, b: Sphere): boolean {
  return true;
}

function intersectSphereBox(a: Sphere, b: Box): boolean {
  return intersectBoxSphere(b, a);
}

function createIntersectFunctionMap(...mapping: [string, IntersectFunction][]): Map<string, IntersectFunction> {
  const map = new Map<string, IntersectFunction>();
  for (const [key, value] of mapping) {
    map.set(key, value);
  }
  return map;
}

const map = createIntersectFunctionMap(
  ["sphere,sphere", intersectSphereSphere],
  ["box,box", intersectBoxBox],
  ["box,sphere", intersectBoxSphere],
  ["sphere,box", intersectSphereBox]
);
```

error:

```
"message": "Type '(a: Sphere, b: Sphere) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'IntersectFunction'.\n  Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.\n    Type 'Shape' is not assignable to type 'Sphere'.\n      Property 'radius' is missing in type 'Box' but required in type 'Sphere'."

Type '(a: Sphere, b: Sphere) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'IntersectFunction'.
  Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
    Type 'Shape' is not assignable to type 'Sphere'.
      Property 'radius' is missing in type 'Box' but required in type 'Sphere'.
```

It seems to be that typescript can't "narrow" Shape into Sphere, and I suspect into any other shapes that compose the union.

I'm wondering if there's something I'm doing wrong here, or perhaps a better way to go about this.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have much to do with discriminated unions and has a lot to do with contravariance of functions in their parameter types.  If you have type `A extends B` then the function type `(b: B) => void` extends `(a: A) => void` and not vice versa.  A function that only accepts a `Sphere` as its first input cannot be used as a function that accepts a `Shape` as its first input.  [See this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3E4Ew).  So you're indeed trying to do something wrong. Does that fully address your question? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I was planning on using this map inside another function which did the run-time type checking so hadn't considered the potential for that kind of runtime error.